# iOS7 [UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] Crash SEGV_ACCERR

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have a crash that is occurring on iOS7 only.  it is random reproduce, The problem is there is no user code in the stack trace so it is proving difficult to track down，Please help me guys.

Thank you

Crash Log：

```
Exception Type: SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x6001c121
Crashed Thread: 0

Thread 0 Crashed: 
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39c36636 objc_msgSend + 15
1  UIKit                          0x318b2fd6 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] +  30
2  UIKit                          0x318b2fb0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] +  44
3  UIKit                          0x3189e716 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +  374
4  UIKit                          0x318b2a2e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] +  590
5  UIKit                          0x318b2700 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] +  528
6  UIKit                          0x318ad6ca -[UIWindow sendEvent:] +  758
7  UIKit                          0x318828cc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] +  196
8  UIKit                          0x31880f76 __UIApplicationHandleEventQueue +  7102
9  CoreFoundation                 0x2f02c20a ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ +  14
 +  14
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2f02b6da ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 +  206
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2f029ece ___CFRunLoopRun +  622
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2ef94ebe CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 515
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2ef94ca2 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
14 GraphicsServices               0x33ebb662 GSEventRunModal + 135
15 UIKit                          0x318e114c UIApplicationMain + 1131
16 IPadTest                       0x00957eca main (main.m:19)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x3a139ab6 _start +  2
```

Comment: Enable Exception breakpoint, which gives more information about the crash. It is difficult to answer with this limited information, for Exception breakpoint check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: Just drop support for iOS 7 ;)

Comment: The problem is on release package. when debug this problem is not reproduce.